# Applying conditions to dictionary key values while traversing through them

Tags: python, dictionary

The Dictionary is as given below:

```
goodDay= {'Class':[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'Grade':[1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]}
```

I want to code this way that i should get the count of "1" and also "0" in Class when my grade has value "1" and also vice versa i.e. when my grade has value "0".
So i will have to traverse through the list values for both and Class and Grade and then may be put this condition while segregating. Please help. Thanks

Comment: This is really hard to understand. Could you please provide the output you are looking for given your sample data above? Also, if this is homework, as it is reasonable to believe, please tag the question as such.

Comment: @hughbrown When Grade value == 1 Count of Class values with value 1?? and Count of Class values with value 0??                                                           Similarly when Grade value  == 0 Count of Class values with value 1?? and Count of Class values with value 0??

Comment: Downvote because of what hughdbrown said and the fact that you've already been told this in your last question. Edit: The addition isn't much better... which of the dozen integers in the values should be considered? The first, the last, the nth, the one occuring most frequently, ... ?

Comment: @Delnan I am still struggling to solve this and I think this is the complete problem statement

Answer (score 1):

This counts the number of `c`s (classes) which are 1 when `g` (grades) is 1:

```
In [5]: sum(c for c,g in zip(goodDay['Class'],goodDay['Grade']) if g)
Out[5]: 4
```

And this gives the number of `g`s that are 1 when `c` is 1:

```
In [6]: sum(g for c,g in zip(goodDay['Class'],goodDay['Grade']) if c)
Out[6]: 4
```

Comment: Thaanks for the answer but i did not understand the meaning of In[5] Out [5], In[6] and Out[6]

Comment: Those are produced by his python interpreter. Probably ipython.